# Структура онлайн чата с вебсокетами

Tags: websocket, проектирование

Мне нужно сделать онлайн чат в веб-приложении. Буду использовать вебсокеты. И хочу чтобы они использовались во всём приложении совсем без http запросов.

Мне вот что интересно.

1. Как в таком случае делать маршрутизацию? Т.е. при http я просто использую разные методы запроса и url, что позволяет мне понять какая функция должна обрабатывать этот запрос. Как поступить с вебсокетом? Мб есть готовые протоколы, чтобы не изобретать свой велосипед?
2. Мне нужен функционал, который определяет онлайн человек или нет. Если нет, то когда был. Мне не нравится идея с сохранением последнего действия, т.к. это не совсем точно. Я хочу проверять есть ли сейчас активный вебсокет с этим пользователем. Если есть, то человек онлайн. Нет - оффлайн, а в базе сохранено время, когда было разорвано последние соединение. Я могу сделать глобальный стор для всего приложения, где буду хранить объекты сокетов вместе с id пользователя. Это позволит мне находить нужный вебсокет. Но тут проблема в том, что если приложение начнёт масштабироваться и размещаться на нескольких серверах, то это перестанет работать. Как тут быть? Идею сохранять информацию о наличии сокета в какой-нибудь nosql или inmemory базе данных я откидываю. Мне может понадобиться отправить уведомление пользователю через сокет, когда другой пользователь что-то сделал. А вариант с базой не позволит мне получить объект сокета. Понятно что между серверами должно быть какое-то общение, но как мне в таком случае понять на какой сервер нужно отправить запрос? Тут может быть очень много вариантов изобретения велосипедов. А я очень не хочу этого делать. Есть какие-то best practices для таких случаев? Как будет правильнее?

Я не думаю что язык программирования имеет тут какое-то значение, но всё же напишу: golang

Comment: А какой обычно фреймворк для веб разработки Вы используете в Go?

Comment: @S.H. Для http сервисов с непостоянным соединением - пакет `net/http`